# how to correctly return a reference to a mutated linked list in rust?

Tags: rust, linked-list, ownership

I am solving a leetcode problem in Rust, it's a [linked list problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-nth-node-from-end-of-list/).

The part that I am stuck at is that I have a working algorithm, but I wasn't able to return from the function, below is my solution

```
    pub fn remove_nth_from_end(head: Option<Box<ListNode>>, n: i32) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {
        let mut cursor = head.clone().unwrap();
        let mut count: i32 = 0;

        while cursor.next != None {
            count += 1;
            cursor = cursor.next.unwrap();
        }

        let mut n = count - n;

        let mut new_cursor = head.unwrap();

        while n != 0 {
            n -= 1;
            new_cursor = new_cursor.next.unwrap();
        }

        new_cursor.next = new_cursor.next.unwrap().next;

        head // <- error: used of moved value
    }
```

I first clone the `head` so that I can iterate through the linked list to get its total number of nodes.

Then, I will have to remove one node from the list, hence I'm not cloning the `head`, instead I use it directly, in this case the variable is moved. So after I am done removing the node, I would like to return the `head`, so that I can return the whole linked list.

However, because of the ownership system in rust, I wasn't able to return a moved value. The problem is I couldn't clone the value as well because if I were to clone, then the `head` is no longer pointing to the linked list where I removed one node from it.

How would one solve this kind of issue in Rust? I am fairly new to Rust, just picked up the language recently.

Comment: Hello, the problem is in "let mut new_cursor = head.unwrap();" because trait Copy is not implemented. You test at "https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cb6e7d4517cc6e5704be5591bbd68ebf"

Comment: Note: you probably need to read this tutorial that exists out there: [Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/index.html) - It probably contains the answers you need, though it will also make you cry on how "fun" they can be with the strict ownership model of Rust.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `&mut` over the nodes and then use `Option::take` to take ownership of the nodes while leaving `None` behind. Use those combinations to mutate the list:

```rust
impl Solution {
    pub fn remove_nth_from_end(mut head: Option<Box<ListNode>>, mut n: i32) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {
        match n {
            0 => head.and_then(|node| node.next),
            _ => {
                let mut new_head = &mut head;
                while n > 0 {
                    new_head = if let Some(next) = new_head {
                        &mut next.next
                    } else {
                        return head;
                    };
                    n -= 1;
                }
                let to_skip = new_head.as_mut().unwrap().next.take();
                new_head.as_mut().map(|node| {
                    node.next = if let Some(mut other_node) = to_skip {
                        other_node.next.take()
                    } else {
                        None
                    };
                });
                head
            }
        }

    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bba420c616faa30b16379974a8887843)

Disclaimer: This do not implement it working from the end of the list but from the beginning of it. Didn't realize that part, but that should be the problem itself.